# IIS Windows Authentication keeps prompting on SERVER

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012

I have inherited an ASP.net web application running on Windows server 2012 and IIS.  The application works fine but there was no Test instance.  When attempting to set one up I tried browsing both Live and Test instances within IIS on the server but both continually prompt for credentials as set to Windows Authentication. While a Client connection to the Live instance works fine with Windows Authentication.  I checked Windows Authentication was setup within the Web Server's security role on the server manager.  I have tried moving NTLM up above negotiate for these sites' Windows Authentication Providers.  The only thing i found that worked was setting up a registry key for "DisableLoopbackCheck" by doing the following,

1. In Regedit go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa
2. Right-click Lsa >> New >> DWORD Value.
3. Name this DisableLoopbackCheck, and then press ENTER.
4. Right-click DisableLoopbackCheck, and then click Modify.
5. In the Value data box, type 1, and then click OK.
6. Quit Registry Editor, and then restart the website in IIS

However, I wish to ask the following to clarify,

a) Is this the only way to achieve this?  Is there a better way?
b) Will this registry amendment affect the client users on their own machines?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this way:

1. Open the internet properties on the task bar and select security.
   [image]
2. Choose Internet click custom level. You’ll find user authentication at the bottom of list.
   [image]
3. Change the policy to automatic logon with current username and password.